# Open XDR file in Python

Tags: python, idl, xdr

I usually use IDL for data analysis.
So when I open a XDR file, I used openr function with /XDR keyword.
Now I try to change the IDL code to Python, but I dont know how to read the XDR files.

for example in IDL, I can open the file using below sentence

```
openr,1,file,/XDR
```

and read the data using

```
readu,1,h1,h2,h3,h4
readu,1,p_h1,p_h2,p_h3,p_h4
readu,1,p1,p2,p3,p33,p4,p5,p6,AP12
.....
```

however, when I try to read the data in Python

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.readlines()     
u = xdrlib.Unpacker(data)
print('unpacked:', u.unpack_uint(), repr(u.unpack_string()))
```

It doesn't work...
Would you guys please give me some advice ?

Comment: XDR is binary. You can't treat it as a sequence of lines.

Comment: Using f.readlines() probably isn't right for this format. Try just using f.read()

Comment: Just using f =open(file, 'rb')  data = f.read() ? and then unpack the data ? u = xdrlib.Unpacker(data)